# Highlighting value change ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ReactJS, and I was wondering whether it is possible to highlight an element in the DOM when its value has been changed.

I have a list of elements whose values update periodically. While I have no problem animating in the DOM new items coming in to the list or items leaving the list using React's animation library interface, I am struggling to figure out how to detect the actual value change of the existing elements in the list.

Any ideas on how to do so? Thank you!

Comment: There's a lifecycle method fired when properties change:  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your new values are coming down as new props, then you can use the  [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method on the component.  It is called just before the component is updated.

Within that method, you can compare the new values (passed as the argument to the method) and the old values (available as `this.props`).

---

For instance:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
    if(this.props.query != newProps.query) {
        //handle change of query prop
        //may include calls to this.setState()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Laizer. I am trying to implement this and it should work well. However, I am not sure why, but at rerenderings this.props become react formatted objects rather than an originally passed in array. Is this specific to how reactJS operates?

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  props of a component don't change at all; they should have the same value they were assigned with.  I'm wondering if your component props perhaps got rewritten in your component logic?  Modifying props in React is a no-no.  I added an example above, from live code, of checking for a change in props.

Comment: @Lazier. Thank you very much! I got this one working

Comment: I'm curious - what had cause `this.props` to have strange values?

Comment: @Lazier As you said, the props have been modified directly. It was a beginner mistake: I have created a variable pointing to the array in the props. To fix it, instead I created another array and copied the values of the props in, and only then created ReactElements based on the new copy

Comment: As of React 16.3 you should no longer use componentWillReceiveProps.  It has been marked UNSAFE. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, then I decided to create a generic small module to handle it everywhere, that you can install from here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-change-highlight

using

```
yarn add react-change-highlight
```

what you can do to use it is to wrap you part that you want to highlight inside the component itself as follow

```
import ChangeHighlight from 'react-change-highlight';

export default () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <ChangeHighlight>
      <div ref={React.createRef()}>{count}</div>
    </ChangeHighlight>
  );
}
```

and you will find the highlight on change as in the example below

[image]

I hope you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your elements are input elements, you need to use the [onChange](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#interactive-props) event listener. If you want to highlight that element, I would suggest having a CSS class that highlights the element and then conditionally applying it in `render()` based on state (or props if a child).

So for instance, you can have one component, add a handler function and the appropriate listener in the `render()`:

```
handleChange: function(evt) {
    //input was changed, update component state (or call parent method if child)
    this.setState({changed: true});
},

render: function() {
    return (<div>
        <input type="text" 
               className={this.state.changed ? 'highlight' : ''}
               onChange={this.handleChange}
         />
    </div>);
}
```

That should set you in the right direction.

Comment: This will highlight if the user types something in the box, is that what @AnikDang wants? I thought they wanted a highlight when the data changes without the user causing it.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure based on the OP. It doesn't specify what the elements are or how they change.

Comment: But if you think about it... The highlight is to bring attention attention to the fact that the data just changed, if the user changed it, it's kind of pointless, even annoying

Comment: Sometimes input change colors when dealing with validation systems (i.e. you start to type an incorrectly formatted input and the field highlights red while you type until it is correct). I had assumed OP was asking for something like that. Maybe that was an incorrect assumption. Again, the post is not incredibly clear.

Comment: agree, just taking my best guess based on what was said